# Project Euler #10 - sum of primes below two million

Tags: java, programming-challenge, primes

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
>
> Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

```
public class Java {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();

    long sum = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++) {
        boolean isPrime = true;

        if ((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0) && (i!=2 || i!=3 || i!=5)) {
            isPrime = false;
        } else {
            for (int j = 5; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j = j + 6) {
                if (i % j == 0 || i % (j + 2) == 0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isPrime == true) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(end - start);
}
```

This is probably not efficient since i am using a lot of `if`-`else` statements and conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all, sorry, but your code is buggy. You are missing 2 and 3, because of this:

```
if ((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0)
```

...since this will be true for 2 and 3. So your result is off by 5.

Also this part is 100% useless:

```
(i!=2 || i!=3 || i!=5))
```

How many values for i you can imagine for which this statement is false?

- Let's try i = 1 -> true, because 1 != 2 (i != 2)
- Now we try i = 2 -> true, because 2 != 3 (i != 3)
- Now we try i = 3 -> true, because 3 != 2 (i != 2)
- Last try: i = 5 -> true, because 5 != 2 (i != 2)

So, this statement is always true.

Anyway, another solution (getting more speed by sacrificing memory) would be to not calculate if every number is a prime, but do something like this...

```
final int limit = 2000 * 1000;

final boolean[] knownNotPrime = new boolean[limit + 1];

long sum = 0;

for (int i = 2; i < limit; i++) {

    if (!knownNotPrime[i]) {
        sum += i;

        for (int j = 2; j <= (limit / i); j++) {
            knownNotPrime[j * i] = true;
        }
    }

}
```

In other words, for every prime you calculate the multiples (up to the limit) and store them in a boolean array (you could decrease the memory by a factor of 8 by using a bitfield, just didn't want to complicate the whole thing).

Since "being not a multiple of any number lesser than itself" is pretty much the definition of "prime", you already know if a number is a prime when you reach it and it's not marked in the array. And if it isn't, you know that it's a multiple of some lesser prime - and thus, all it's multiples will already be known as non-prime, no need to re-calculate them.

Your code takes around 217ms to run, mine takes 17, but on the other hand, mine takes way more than 12 times the memory, even if you used a bitfield.

Note: After using google and trying to remember what I learned in school, this is probably a variation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes and I have no idea how good this implementation is. Probably there are much better solutions out there, I guess.

Comment: Aah... my bad.... i deliberately tried to remove 2 and 3 and i wanted to add 5 to the result... but forgot to put it in the code

Comment: As a side note, you can write long numbers like this: `2_000_000`. Then you don't need to have a `*` that means nothing but looks like it might.

Comment: As long as you are sure that you are using Java 7 or higher, yes.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>         if ((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0) && (i!=2 || i!=3 || i!=5)) {
> ```

If `i` is divisible by 2 or 3, it will never be equal to 5.  So you could just say

```
        if ((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0) && (i!=2 && i!=3)) {
```

Note that I changed the `||` to `&&`, as the original logic was incorrect.  `(i!=2 || i!=3)` is true for all `i`.  When `i` is 2, it's not 3, so true.  And vice versa.

But we can do better.  Rather than saying

> ```
>     long sum = 0;
>
>     for (int i = 2; i < 2000000; i++) {
> ```

Say

```
    // sum 2 and 3 manually
    long sum = 5;

    // 5 is the first prime after 2 and 3
    for (int i = 5; i < 2000000; i++) {
```

and then you can just say

```
        if ((i % 2 == 0 || i % 3 == 0)) {
```

which is much simpler.

Be careful of things like

> ```
>             for (int j = 5; j <= Math.sqrt(i); j = j + 6) {
> ```

This relies on the compiler realizing that `Math.sqrt(i)` is invariant in regards to the `j` loop and optimizing it out.  If the compiler does not do that, it will do an expensive square root operation on every iteration of the loop.  Something like

```
            for (int j = 5, m = (int) Math.sqrt(i); j <= m; j = j + 6) {
```

may be more efficient.

Note:  I tend to agree that this problem is well suited to a Sieve of Eratosthenes.  My suggestions are less for this problem and more for coding in general.  If you do use a Sieve as suggested in [@FlorianSchaetz's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/102079/71574) consider

```
        for (int j = i * i; j <= limit; j += i) {
            knownNotPrime[j] = true;
        }
```

As all multiples of `i` less than `i * i` would have been picked up already.

Note that starting `j` at `i * i` rather than `i` saves calculating both `limit / i` and `i * j` at the cost of changing `j++` to `j += i`.

Comment: Thanks for being spot on .... yes...  changing the logic was a very valuable idea....  My logic was like spaghetti... :D